# How can I set a Google Cloud Storage object to be publicly visible when uploading it via a signed URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm following [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/signed_urls/generate_signed_urls.py) guide and have a solution which is uploading objects to Google Cloud storage using the signed URL and the XML REST API (e.g. `curl -v -X POST $URL -F "file=@test.jpg"`).

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to set the ACL on these objects such that they'll be publicly visible. I have tried using the `x-goog-acl` header (and various capitalizations in both the signed URL and request headers) and the `acl` query parameter without success.

I assume this must be possible, as it's referenced in the API documentation and all of the client libraries allow you to do this. I have a feeling I'm screwing something up in my URL signing method (even though the header appears in the signed URL: `https://storage.googleapis.com/foo/test.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=STUFF&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-goog-acl&acl=public-read&MORE-STUFF`), but I'm sort of at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to upload your object using the XML REST API, and you want that object to be publicly accessible by anyone.

To do that, you can follow this [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#upload-object-xml) to upload your object. To use a file instead of the data binary, just replace `--data-binary @[OBJECT]` by `-T [PATH_TO_FILE]`. After doing that, to make the object public, you need to follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#make-object-public-xml). Doing this will make your object always accessible by anyone, and you do not need the signed URL for anything else.

On the other hand, if what you want is to grant anyone access to an object for a limited time, then you want to generate that [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which is what the guide you mention does.

**EDIT**

I think I have made it work now the way you wanted. 
First, you would want to modify the code in the tutorial, adding another query parameter:

```
query_parameters['X-Goog-Acl'] = 'public-read'
```

Now you can run the Python code with the desired parameters (using method `PUT`), and use another PUT with the signed URL, something like this:

```
curl -v -X PUT $SIGNED_URL -T "[PATH_TO_FILE]" -H "content-type:text/plain" -H "x-goog-acl:public-read"
```

In my example, I am creating the signed URL to upload a plain text file.

I have tried this extensively and it works.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to confirm, though, there is no way to set the object's ACL to `public-read` when creating it? You _must_ make a separate request to do this? That's not ideal if an anonymous end user is making the request via signed URL because they'll have to go through the URL signing request/response and REST request/response flow a second time.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now I think it works as you wanted.